# Maven not recognized in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have installed Tomcat 7 on Windows 8, on which Jenkins is deployed. I configured the JDK, Ant and Maven in the Jenkin settings. In the Maven section, I gave a name as LocalMaven and the MAVEN_HOME as `C:\Techie\apache-maven`. When I did a test build, it gave me the following error that the mvn.bat is not recognized. Then I checked by entering mvn command in CMD. It gave some maven statements, which means maven is available in the `PATH` variables.

After googling, I changed the MAVEN_HOME as `**%M2_HOME%\bin**` in Jenkin-Maven configuration. Still it did not work.

**LOG:**

- `[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"mvn.bat -f HighScoresServiceClient compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'`
- '`mvn.bat`' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file
- Build step '`Invoke top-level Maven targets`' marked build as failure
- Finished: `FAILURE`

**Edited: Added the analysis**

The command executed by Jenkins is `[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"mvn.bat -f String-replacer compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'` where mvn.bat is not a valid command and so Jenkins errors out as follows that `'mvn.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` I think Jenkins should call the command as mvn and not mvn.bat. Can some experts correct me if I am wrong? Please let me know how to change this behaviour if I am right.

**Edited: Attached the Configuration**
[image: Maven-JDK-Git Configuration in Jenkins]

[image: Maven is available in the PATH variables]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose your Tomcat server is running as a Windows service.

Did you create your MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME as system environment variables? (idem for your PATH)

Another solution is to configure your variables in the apache-tomcat/bin/setenv.bat file:

```
set MAVEN_HOME=C:\Techie\apache-maven
set PATH=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: I tried creating the system variables. It did not work. I even added the contents into setenv.bat file. It did not help :(

Comment: When you configured Maven in your Jenkins settings, you declared the installation in the Maven section? Did you try the "install automatically" option?

Comment: A last test, on your job, can you try to use the Inject Env plugin and force the PATH to %PATH%;C:\Techie\apache-maven\bin? Just to check if this solved your pb.

Comment: This time, I get a different error. Path is displayed. ----ERROR LOG---   [EnvInject] - Executing and processing the following script content: 
%PATH%;C:\Techie\apache-maven\bin

[workspace] $ cmd /c call c:\Techie\servers\apache-tomcat-7.0.61\temp\hudson2494005029985865936.bat
'C:\Apps\Java\jdk1.7.0_67/bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Anand\.jenkins\jobs\test-build-3\workspace>exit 9009 
[EnvInject] - Script executed. The exit code is 9009.
[EnvInject] - Fail the build.
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Can you post some screen copies to show us how you declared your Maven/Java/Ant stuff with Jenkins?

Comment: Your settings seem OK. On your Jenkins job, did you choose your "LocalMaven" in the Maven version listbox?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, which really helped. It was having the default value and once I changed it to LocalMaven, it worked fine. Thanks a lot Bruno...

Comment: @BrunoLavit Thank you bruno :)

Answer (score 5):

I bet you've installed Maven 3.3 that has mvn.bat renamed to mvn.cmd

There is a report on this issue in Jenkins JIRA: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27525

Comment: This issue is resolved and available by upgrading Jenkins. To get it to work I upgraded Jenkins itself and the Maven Integration plugin. To get it to work I ALSO had to explicitly specify the new Maven version in the project configuration, even though it was configured to use the "default" Maven version which I updated to point to the new 3.3 one.